# How do I prevent results from showing the header of the interactive python shell?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In `org-mode`, if I execute my first command like this,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :results output
t = [1,2,3]
print(t)
#+END_SRC
```

I obtain

```
#+RESULTS:
: Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
: [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
: >>> python.el: native completion setup loaded
: [1, 2, 3]
```

How do I simply get:

```
#+RESULTS:
: [1, 2, 3]
```

Notice that if I `C-c C-c` again, the message goes away (sinc ethe process now exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but it should work:

```
(setq org-babel-python-command "python -ic ''")
```

See thread https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-March/569778.html for reason of the "-c ''" weird approach to suppress message.